# Komascript heading issues using `\newpairofpagestyles`?

Tags: errors, koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearscrheadfoot                                       
%\chead*{\mytitle}
\lehead*{\headmark}                                     
\rohead*{\headmark}                 
\cfoot*{\pagemark}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\newpairofpagestyles{myFMstyle}{%
    \clearscrheadfoot%
    \rhead*{\headmark}
    \cfoot*{\pagemark}  
}%
%\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{myFMstyle} <- Runs fine when this is commented out

\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
\printnomenclature

\nomenclature{c}{speed}
test
\end{document}
```

Supposed output:

[image]

With the `\renewcommand` line commented out, it runs fine. But when I uncomment it and try to run it, I get the following error:

> Undefined control sequence. \end{document}

What exactly am I doing wrong?

EDIT: The error is not caused by `nomencl` but by the usage of `\newpairofpagestyles` in which the `\rhead`-command causes the issues.

Comment: Your error is inside the `\newpairofpagestyles{myFMstyle}{...}` definition. If you remove everything `nomencl` related and insert a `\chapter{test}` you get the same error.

Comment: Also your error is not `Undefined control sequence. \end{document}` but `Undefined control sequence \rhead`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `\rhead` and `\lhead` in `\newpairofpagestyles`. Instead you should use `\rehead` for right head on equal pages and `\rohead` for right head on odd pages. Alternatively you could also use `\ohead` and `\ihead` for outer and inner side. With this your MWE should look like this:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearscrheadfoot                                       
%\chead*{\mytitle}
\lehead*{\headmark}% you might use \ohead*{\headmark} instead of \lehead*{}...\rohead*{}
\rohead*{\headmark}% you might use \ohead*{\headmark} instead of \lehead*{}...\rohead*{}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\newpairofpagestyles{myFMstyle}{%
    \clearscrheadfoot%
    \ohead*{\headmark}% here you should use \ohead{}, \ihead{}, \rohead{} or \rehead{} instead of \rhead{}
    \cfoot*{\pagemark}  
}%
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{myFMstyle}

\begin{document}
\chapter{test}

test
\end{document}
```

The usage of `nomencl` shouldn't change anything in this example.

Additionally, if your `myFMstyle` matches your `scrheadings`-style (like in this example), why don't you just use `\renewcommand{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}`?

EDIT: Note that the command `\printnomenclature` doesn't set the `\headmark`. Because of this you should call a `\markboth{Nomenclature}{Nomenclature}` after the call of `\printnomenclature`.

Comment: Only as an addendum: Using `scrhack` from [current KOMA-Script Prerelease](https://komascript.de/current) also adds running heads to `\printnomenclature`.

Comment: @Schweinebacke thanks, I didn't know that.